# How do I use NextAuth to access a JWT token for use in later API calls?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, jwt, next-auth

I have a project running on NextJS (with typescript) that's using the NextAuth.js library in order to handle login authentication. In the api directory `api/auth/[...nextauth].ts`
I'm using [credentials](https://next-auth.js.org/configuration/providers/credentials) in order to send a POST request to a private API that returns a JWT token. The storing of the token and login authentication works fine. However, I need to be able to access and use the token to make authorized calls to the API.

My expectation is that I can access the stored jwt token, send it as part of my api request for future api calls in order to access the private api endpoints.

I've tried accessing the token using the useSession hook:

```
const { data: sessionData, status } = useSession();
const { accessToken }: any = sessionData;
```

However, When I try this, I get an error:

```
TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'accessToken' of 'sessionData' as it is undefined.
```

I've looked into the docs and I found that I need to add jwt and session callbacks which I've done:

```
  callbacks: {
    async jwt({ token, account }: any) {
      // Persist the OAuth access_token to the token right after signin
      if (account) {
        token.accessToken = account?.accessToken;
      }
      return token;
    },
    async session({ session, token, user }: any) {
      // Send properties to the client, like an access_token from a provider.
      session.accessToken = token.accessToken;

      return session;
    },
  },
```

However, I still get the same undefined error.

How do I properly access the jwt token?

Answer (score 0):

To give access of a new field: "role", I do this change :

```
  callbacks: {
    async session({ session, token }) {
      session.user.role = token.role;
      return session;
    },
    async jwt({ token, user }) {
      if (!token.role) {
        token.role = user.role;
      }
      return token;
    },
  },
```

I think you overwrite the value here : `token.accessToken = account?.accessToken;`. Maybe, you can check if the value is not already defined.